# Bind Listview to two different object collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Is it possible to bind the GridViewColumns of a listview to different object collections ? 
if yes, how?

Comment: Any online tutorial about that?

Comment: What would it even *mean* to bind to two different object collections.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the Columns to show data from two different sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The `ListView` has a single `ItemsSource`, so can only have a single source collection. You will have to combine these two collections into a single source for the grid, perhaps by adding a view model (MVVM).